# How to configure an Identity column using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How do I create an Auto increment identity column in Entity Framework Core?

Obviously I can do it using fluent API for EF6 for example.

Comment: Nothing special I think, the default working of an Id field is an incrementing identity column. Did this give you a problem?

Comment: It's been changed to be a sequence by default. :(

Comment: I haven't used EF7 myself yet but when I look at [examples](http://chad.tolkien.id.au/asp-net-vnext-mvc6-ground-up-3-entity-framework-7/) [online](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/01/17/asp-net-5-and-angularjs-part-4-using-entity-framework-7), each model just has an `int Id` field as primary key.

Comment: as per Rowan Miller "Configuring a column as identity will still be easy in EF7, we're just looking at making the default be sequences instead of identity." ~ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/05/19/ef7-new-platforms-new-data-stores.aspx

Comment: @AndrewDuffy I see a number of different answers changing, shifting with newer and updated versions of the framework. At the moment, the accepted answer isn't the best fit one. Would you mind revising and re-accepting in order to point out for future readers which one is to be preferred, please?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since there is very little EF7 documentation, much of what we know we have to glean from the source or unit tests.  According to the following two unit tests in the EF7 source...

<s>[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/test/EntityFramework.SqlServer.FunctionalTests/StoreGeneratedSqlServerTestBase.cs) and [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/test/EntityFramework.SqlServer.FunctionalTests/SequenceEndToEndTest.cs)</s>

You would configure a property for Identity like this:

```
b.Property(e => e.Id).ForSqlServer().UseIdentity();
```

And you would configure a property for Sequences like this:

```
ForSqlServer().UseSequence();
```

The urls have changed due to the aspnet-core reorg, and the methods have also changed since this was first asked.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/release/2.1/test/EFCore.SqlServer.FunctionalTests/StoreGeneratedSqlServerTest.cs) and [Here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/dev/test/EFCore.SqlServer.FunctionalTests/SequenceEndToEndTest.cs)

```
if (_useSequence) 
{
    b.Property(e => e.Identifier).ForSqlServerUseSequenceHiLo();
} 
else 
{
    b.Property(e => e.Identifier).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
}
```

It's possible these urls might change again (which is why I include the relevant code), but it's ridiculously easy to just look at the url and go to the site and figure out what the new url is.

Really, the whole point of my answer is that you can figure this stuff out yourself just by going and looking at the unit tests in the source code on GitHub.  You shouldn't need someone to spoon feed it to you.

EDIT: Updated links to version 2.1 (still works for 1.1 and 2.0 as well)

Comment: I am receiving this error, how do I fix this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49715467/entity-framework-core-2-0-error-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-usesqlserveri

Comment: @AppleBook89 - This still seems to be used, are you including the correct namespace?  See the current unit tests: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverpropertybuilderextensions.usesqlserveridentitycolumn?view=efcore-2.0

Comment: I am getting 'MissingFieldException': Field Not found when using Identity column. I cannot find the reason for that. I am using DB First approach.

Comment: @SuyashGupta - That means the expected column is not named what EF is expecting.  You will probably have to map it manually.

Comment: Column name is same in the code as well as in db. The problem occurs only when I am setting my primary key as Identity column. If I remove the identity property, the insertion happens without any issue.

Comment: @SuyashGupta - Actually, MissingFieldException is a runtime exception, and has nothing to do with Databases.  It happens when you recompile only part of your app, and another part is compiled expecting a field in a class that is no longer there.  I'd suggest recompiling everything in your app.

Answer (score 59):

In latest version of EF7 there is a new extension method to set identity column

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
  modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(b =>
  {
    b.HasKey(e => e.Identifier);
    b.Property(e => e.Identifier).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
  });
}
```

Comment: Note: ValueGeneratedOnAdd does not actually set the column to be an Identity column, and will fail if it is not.

Comment: Corroborating with official doc: [HasKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys#fluent-api) and [ValueGeneratedOnAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add-fluent-api)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch are you sure? I [read](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/valuegeneratedonadd-method) its equivalent of `DatabaseGenerated` attribute with Identity!

Comment: @S.Serpooshan - That's not official documentation.  See [ValueGeneradOnAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add-fluent-api) comment `This just lets EF know that values are generated for added or updated entities, it does not guarantee that EF will setup the actual mechanism to generate values.`

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch i didn't test it yet, but when i read the official docs and its more details in its ['Value generated on add'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add) section, it seems that it will generate the auto id for an identity column. may be what that statement tries to say, is just for special data types (other than integer identity), like as `DateTime` that we need to set a 'default value' for them such that program know how to generate new data for them

Comment: I just checked the generated database and the column definition in SQL Server is "Is Identity" = Yes

Answer (score 24):

Looks like they changed it once again and the new method now is:

```
.UseIdentityColumn()
```

Answer (score 10):

With latest bits EF Core 1.0 and up you should use

```
builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property<int>(nameof(ApplicationUser.AccountNo))
            .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn()
```

Comment: thanks. UseSqlServerIdentityColumn is how its done now, including the RC1 final, so I guess this API is going to stick.

Comment: Thanks, update the answer to explicitly indicate that RC1 supported

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to do it explicitly in the event that you want to OR it's not the default behaviour.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{    
  modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(b =>
  {
    b.Key(e => e.Identifier);
    b.Property(e => e.Identifier).ForSqlServer().UseIdentity();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute in your model.

For example:

```
public class Blog
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your example do not reflect your response... 