# SQL Azure database - confusing error message - SQL Server

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-sql-database

I tried inserting data into an Azure SQL database with this code:

```
Users user = new Users()
                {
                    username = txtUsername.Text,
                    userPassword = txtPassword.Text
                };

await App.client.GetTable<Users>().InsertAsync(user);
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationExecution: No id member found on type Model.Users

So I checked my C# model class:

```
public class Users
{
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_id")]
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string userPassword { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to change the json property from `user_id` to `id` like this:

```
public class Users
{
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string userPassword { get; set; }
}
```

When I run it again, I still get an error:

> InvalidOperationExecution: No id member found on type Model.Users

What should I do? I already provided `user_id` at first but it shows error, where did I go wrong?

This is my database

```
Create table Users
(
    user_id  int primary key identity(1,1),
    username varchar(30) not null,
    user     varchar(30) not null,
)
```

Comment: Please share the code where you declare which column is the primary key.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JzxYPnX.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is actually not so confusing.

`"InvalidOperationExecution: No id member found on type Model.Users"` means that there is no member that is a primary key or id for this item.

There are many ways to specify the key. One way is use KeyAttribute.

```
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int user_id { get; set; }
```

Fee helpful links:

- [Code First Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#key),
- [Fluent API - Configuring and Mapping Properties and Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties#configuring-a-primary-key)
- [How to configure an Identity column using Entity Framework Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661867/how-to-configure-an-identity-column-using-entity-framework-core)